# how to loop through xml using php with different nodes

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

here is my xml I want to loop propertyList and get residential and rental nodes, can someone help me to know how can I do it, also when I print_r the propertylist node it returns null array

```
<propertyList>
<residential modTime="2020-11-10-11:35:06" status="current">
<agentID/>
<uniqueID>eagle_659872</uniqueID>
<authority value="exclusive"/>
<underOffer value="no"/>
<isHomeLandPackage value="no"/>
<listingAgent id="1">
  <name>Matt Luff</name>
</listingAgent>
<price display="yes">900000</price>
<priceView/>
<landDetails>
  <area unit="squareMeter"/>
  <frontage/>
  <depth side="left"/>
  <depth side="right"/>
  <depth side="rear"/>
 </landDetails>
 </residential>


<rental modTime="2020-11-09-12:56:01" status="current">
<agentID/>
<uniqueID>eagle_662855</uniqueID>
<listingAgent id="1">
  <name>Leasing Specialists </name>
</listingAgent>
<priceView>$430 per week</priceView>
<bond>1720</bond>
 <landDetails>
  <area unit="squareMeter"/>
  <frontage/>
  <depth side="left"/>
  <depth side="right"/>
  <depth side="rear"/>
 </landDetails>
 </rental>
 </propertyList>
```

Comment: What do  you mean by "get residential and rental nodes"? What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: actually i want to run a single loop and to get residential child nodes and rental child nodes, right now m using 2 loops to get all residential and rental child nodes.  in this above xml i only paste some part .. there many nodes named residential and same as rental too

Comment: i will like to run a for each loop on propertylist and to get all children inside it but unfortunately dont know why proprtylist returns null array

Comment: Again, I don't know what "get all children" etc. means. What **exactly** is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Xpath expressions. It allows you to fetch nodes and values from the DOM.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(getXML());
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$expression = '/propertyList/residential|/propertyList/rental';
foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $property) {
    echo $property->localName, "\n";
    echo 'ID: ', $xpath->evaluate('string(uniqueID)', $property);
    echo 'Price: ', $xpath->evaluate('string(priceView)', $property);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
residential
ID: eagle_659872
Price: 

rental
ID: eagle_662855
Price: $430 per week
```

An expression like `/propertyList/residential` will return nodes matching this location path. `|` separates alternative expressions. An starting `/` anchors the expression to the document root.

`$xpath->evaluate('string(uniqueID)', $property)` evaluates the expression `string(uniqueID)` with the `$property` node as context. It contains a string cast, so it will return the text content of the first `uniqueID` child element node.

This are only the most basic features. Xpath allows for a lot more complex expressions with conditions.